# Java style polymorphism in C#?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I want to use Java style polymorphism in C#. Is it possible?

Here is an example that does not compile

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(2);
        Square square = new Square(3);
        printID(square);
    }

    public void printID(Shape s){
           Console.WriteLine ("id is " + s.id);
    }
}

public class Shape{
       public int id;
}

public class Triangle: Shape{
       float b;
       float height;

       float area(){
             return b*height/2;
       }

       public Triangle(int k){
            id=k;
       }
}

public class Square: Shape{
       float side;

       float area(){
             return side*side;
       }

       public Square(int k){
              id=k;
       }

}
}
```

The message is

> MyClass.cs(11,4): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `HelloWorld.Program.printID(HelloWorld.Shape)'

Thanks!

Comment: oh my, that is embarrassing, thanks Sergey.   Works fine now

Answer (score 6):

Error is not related to polymorphism - you are calling non-static method from static method `Main`. You should make `printID` static as well.

```
public static void printID(Shape s){
    Console.WriteLine("id is " + s.id);
}
```

Also I suggest you to:

- Stick with C# naming guidelines when you are writing C# code. Methods and properties should have *PascalCase* names.
- Use properties instead of public fields
- If any shape should have and id, consider to create `public Shape(int id)` constructor in base class and call that constructor from derived classes via `: base(id)`
- Improve naming - if you are passing id, then call variable `id` instead of `k`.